# Java & Spring JDBC: How to simulate table in database doesn't exist for testing (without actually dropping or renaming it)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, integration-testing

I have a Java application that talks to a MySQL database using Spring JDBC Templates.  In one of my tests I want to simulate a table not being there in an integration test, however I cannot actually temporarily drop/recreate or rename the table in our testing database for a variety of reasons.

I also don't want to mock out the particular DAO method call that would hit the table that throws the error in case going forward we use other methods.  I want to do something like intercept the sql before it goes off to the database and replace the table name (if present) with a bogus name--or something else to the same effect.

Test driven development for the win!

Comment: Is this a unit test? If so, if it fails, do you care?

Comment: Simple. Excecute this test case before the DBA creates the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If interception is what you want, using aspects could be a solution.

- You'd have to create a **pointcut** intercepting, e.g., the call to the specific method "sending the sql before it goes off to the database".
- Then you can create **before/around advice**, in which you can manipulate the data ("replace the table name with a bogus name") before you proceed with the call

See [aspectj](/questions/tagged/aspectj), as well as [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should use EasyMock for tests like these.  There are ways to have a method throw any exception you specify.  If you cannot use this, you have not effectively separated your application layers.

Look at: http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock2_2_Documentation.html, under the heading "Working with Exceptions"

Comment: Usually we use easyMock but since the problem is a non-existant table there could be many data access layer functions that would throw exceptions--some perhaps not even written yet.

Comment: I've never heard of testing for functions that don't even exist yet! This points to that you don't have your data and service layer abstracted enough.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make sense :( Basically if I use one function to interact with that table I could mock it to throw an error.  But if somebody makes a new function that depends on that table unless they remember to also mock it to throw an error to test that table not existing we could miss some things.